# Docker listening on port 3000, but nothing showing on browser

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm building a Node application in Docker. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.artifacts.smit.sise/node:12.19.1

COPY . .

RUN mkdir certs \
    && cd /certs \
    && wget https://artifacts.smit.sise/artifactory/smit-certs-public/smit_ca.pem --no-check-certificate \
    && npm config set cafile /certs/smit_ca.pem \
    && npm config set registry https://artifacts.smit.sise/api/npm/npm


RUN mkdir /common_front/build/static \
    && ln -sf /front/build/assets/* /valisveeb_common_front/build/assets   \
    && ln -sf /front/build/static/* /valisveeb_common_front/build/static  \
    && ln -sf /front/build/generate.options.js/ \
    && ln -sf /front/build/settings.json /valisveeb_common_front/build/settings.json



#RUN cp -f envexample build/.env 
WORKDIR /front/build

RUN ls -la \
    && npm install 

RUN npm run dev

EXPOSE 3000
```

Works fine locally with those exact commands, but when executing the Dockerfile, nothing appears on browser, although the app is saying "listening on port 3000".

This is what I see:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwCqB.png

EDIT:
This is what I run it with:

```
docker build . && docker run -d --restart=always -p 3000:3000 . -it --ignore-certificate-errors
```

Comment: `when executing the Dockerfile, nothing appears on browser`. It looks like there's a bit of misunderstanding here. You "execute" a Dockerfile to build a docker image. Once this image is built, you run one or serveral container(s) using that image. Those container(s) run either with a default command or whichever you pass at runtime. With this in mind, I suspect the second to last line of your Dockerfile should be `CMD npm run dev` (to start the service when container starts, not during build). And you should also tell us what is the command you use to launch your container.

Comment: `localhost` = `127.0.0.1`. You should run `ipconfig` in `CMD` Windows and find your IP (usually `192.168` IP), and then run like `192.168.43.56:3000`

Comment: @Saeed If the container and the browser are on the same host, then localhost works fine with a port forward

Comment: @Zeitounator this is what I run it with docker build . && docker run -d --restart=always -p 3000:3000 . -it --ignore-certificate-errors

Comment: You're running the service during the `docker build` command, so the image build never ends. `docker run` is not even reached.

Answer (score 1):

This instruction:

```
RUN npm run dev
```

runs the service during the image build, so the image is never even built, and no container runs when you try to connect to it. It should be:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```